# Recursive definition of sum of two numbers in terms of the successor function

Tags: algorithms, recursion, number-theory

This is a question from the book `Data structures using C and C++ by Tenenbaum`. Not a homework problem but self-study.

> Recursive definition of a+b, where a and b are non-negative integers, in terms of successor function `succ` defined as
>
> succ(int x)
>       {
>           return(x++);
>       }

I have been thinking how is it possible? Can I change the function? I am not sure from the problem definition in the book. So how can this be done?

Comment: This is the classical definition of addition in Peano arithmetic, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hint:

> a + 3 = succ(succ(succ(a)))

Also, by definition, every natural number is either 0 or the successor of some (smaller) natural number.

Comment: Ok I have thought about this for two weeks but I still don't get it. There needs to be a way to introduce information in the recursive definition so recursion bottoms out. But that would mean changing the successor function. So without changing the function how is it possible to keep track of depth of recursion?

Comment: Here is the definition: $a + 0 = a$, $a + \mathrm{succ}(b) = \mathrm{succ}(a + b)$.